Why does my cat sleep so close
Why has my indoor feral cat become so clingy? Each night she gets a bit closer to me. Tonight she's on my pillow next to me. Am I sick and don't know it? I know I'm depressed due to my sister's passing. Is she trying to comfort me?

how old is she and for how long have you had her,is she spayed?.

She's trying to comfort herself, certainly, and possibly you. She's still figuring out what you will allow, how much she trusts you, and what she is comfortable with. Sone cats want to cuddle and enjoy a friend's warmth at every opportunity, some always want sone space, most are between those extremes... and humans span the same range, so it's always a negotiation.
